# hammerjs swipe feature not working on iOS13 when diagonally swiping

Tags: ios13, hammer.js

Since upgrade to ios13 swiping stop working properly at least it doesn't work how I want it to work.
When swiping from bottom left to top right swiping right event doesn't get fired. Is there any updated version get released soon? I have defined like this in the template for an angular5.0 component. Before ios13 it was working as I expected.

> 

Comment: I'm having similar issues but I don't expect anything to be updated, unfortunately. I actually just sat down to figure an alternative approach.

Comment: The same here. https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/issues/1237